# Suppressing Core Data errors from addPersistentStoreWithType:

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data

I have a custom `NSIncrementalStore`. If there's a problem adding it, the error is automatically logged to the console. 
The problem is that the `options` can contain sensitive data that I obviously don't want logged to the console.

I presume the error is logged by Core Data, which I don't really need, since I already have an NSError argument that I can use appropriately.

For example:

```
@implementation FakeStore

- (BOOL)loadMetadata:(NSError **)error {
  *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"faildomain" code:531 userInfo:nil];
  return NO;
}

@end
```

Attempt at adding the store:

```
  [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator registerStoreClass:[FakeStore class] forStoreType:@"FakeStore"];
  ...
  NSDictionary *options = @{@"option": @"sensitivedata"};
  NSError *error;
  [persistentCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:@"FakeStore" configuration:nil URL:storeUrl
                                            options:options error:&error];
```

The error that is automatically logged to the console:

`CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:FakeStore configuration:(null) URL:<URL> options:{
    option = sensitivedata;
} ... returned error Error Domain=faildomain Code=531 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (faildomain error 531.)" with userInfo dictionary {
}`

A workaround is that the sensitive data shouldn't be passed into the `options` for my store, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Is there anyway to suppress this error?

Answer (score 0):

well you can't turn it off but you should be able to redirect it. Bummer.. needs private API .. is that an option for you?

https://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=_NSSetLogCStringFunction&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=uUKdVe-QN4nj8wfl9AE

tried the first link and found it still worked!

---

if private API is no option: no (and Id file a bug :D)

Comment: It's an OSX app, so I may be able to get away with it, but I'm not sure I will try. Thanks though.